# Remove a word using jQuery not working for me

Tags: jquery

in the following HTML i want to remove the word "To"

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zs2tnevf/5/

```
<td class="tdClass">
  To 
<a title="" class="franchise_0001 " href="">
<img align="middle" src="" alt="" >
</a>  
  This is other text that might have word to also but do not remove
</td>
```

I have tried each of the following with no luck

```
$('td:contains(To)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length === 0;  // exclude divs with children
}).text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/To/g, '');
});


var el = $(".tdClass");
//replace(/word to remove/ig, "");
el.html(el.html().replace(/To/ig, ""));


$('td:contains("To")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("To").join(""));
});
```

Comment: Check console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: checked and irrelevant issue

Comment: 1: the `<td>` element has children, so that solution can't work (in addition to Dan's comment); 2: you set the `g` (global) and `i` (case-insensitive) flags, to enable multiple replacements regardless of case (so 'to' and 'To', and 'TO', are treated exactly the same way), and so it can't/shouldn't work if you only want one replacement. So what identifies the 'To' uniquely from other potential matches?

Comment: explain please , not following , can you provide answer or fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt work because the td is not in a table.

Add this to your html:

```
<table><tr>
...
</tr></table>
```

See this update of your fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zs2tnevf/14/

Then there are some problems with 2 of your scripts:

1) has this problem with this part (probably because the td has children):

```
return $(this).children().length === 0;  // exclude divs with children
```

it will work if you remove this, like in this fddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zs2tnevf/16/

3 has a problem in the selector. Remove the " here:

```
$('td:contains("To")')
```

like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zs2tnevf/17/

Comment: thanks , that did it , and thanks for well informed explanation